# Complex Eigenvalues and systems of 1st-order ODEs

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, eigenvalues-eigenvectors

I am trying to solve $\begin{aligned} \dfrac{dx}{dt} &= x+ y \\ \dfrac{dy}{dt} &= -10 x- y \end{aligned}$.

My strategy is to let $P = \left[\begin{array}{cc}
1 &1\cr
-10 & -1
\end{array}\right]$ and find $\det(P - \lambda I) = 0 $ and I get $\lambda = \pm 3i$.

I am unsure where to go from here.

Comment: Well, the solutions would have the form $\mathbf{v}(t) = e^{\lambda t} \mathbf{v}_0$, and we have Euler's formula to convert complex exponentials into trig functions...does that sound familiar?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'll give some ideas. Your system reads: $$\begin{bmatrix} x'(t) \\ y'(t)\end{bmatrix} = \begin{bmatrix} 1 & 1 \\ -10 & -1\end{bmatrix}\begin{bmatrix} x(t) \\ y(t)\end{bmatrix}.$$That middle matrix has as a characteristic polynomial $$p(t) = t^2 + 9,$$which has roots $\pm 3i$, good. Now we find the eigenvectors associated.

For $3i$: $$\begin{bmatrix} 1-3i & 1 \\ -10 & -1-3i\end{bmatrix}\begin{bmatrix} a \\ b\end{bmatrix} = \begin{bmatrix} 0 \\ 0\end{bmatrix} \implies b = (-1+3i)a,$$ so one eigenvector can be: $${\bf v}_1 = \begin{bmatrix} 1 \\ -1+3i\end{bmatrix} = \begin{bmatrix} 1 \\ -1\end{bmatrix} + \begin{bmatrix} 0 \\ -3i\end{bmatrix}.$$

Now you repeat the procedure for $-3i$ and get some eigenvector ${\bf v}_2$. The complex solution will be: $${\bf z}(t) = c_1e^{3it}{\bf v}_1 + c_2 e^{-3it}{\bf v}_2,\quad c_1,c_2 \in \Bbb R.$$ Use Euler's formula $e^{i\theta} = \cos \theta + i\sin \theta$ to get the real and imaginary parts of the complex solution.

Answer (score 0):

You're right so far. Notice, you can write your system of equations as
$$Z' = P Z,\;\;(1)$$
where $Z=[x\;\;y]^T$.

Thus, the derivative of $Z$ is a 'scaled' (note, it's technically not scaled because $P$ is a matrix) version of itself which is the property that the exponential function has, so we guess (you can check later that the guess will work) that $Z$ takes the form of an exponential function; i.e.,
$$Z=Ue^{\lambda t}\Rightarrow Z' = \lambda U e^{\lambda t}\;\;(2)$$
for some vector $U$. From (1), (2) gives
$$P Ue^{\lambda t} = \lambda  Ue^{\lambda t},$$
so $Ue^{\lambda t}$ is an eigenvector of $P$ and $\lambda$ is an eigenvalue of $P$. Calculating these, and considering (2), we obtain a solution, $Z$, for the system of equations.

How many solutions can you find?